# Template specialization with alternative return type

Tags: c++, c++03

I have a class template member function and I need to create a specialization that differs by the return type. But this is not allowed.

```
template<typename Type>
class Class {
    Type Method(Type Argument) {...}
};

template <>
double Class<int>::Method(int Argument) {...}
```

Can you suggest a workaround ? (With the goal of hiding the templated definition for `int`.)

Comment: Add some policy: `typename ResType<Type>::type Method(Type Argument)`.

Comment: Can you make `method` a member function template, parameterize it on its return type, and set `Type` as the default template parameter?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I'd better avoid it as it will add overhead.

Comment: @YvesDaoust There would be overhead at compile time, not at run-time.

Answer (score 4):

Let's discuss the root of the problem. When you specialize a member function for a class template, it causes the declaration of the class to be instantiated. So your specialized out-of-class definition conflicts with the generated declaration.

A possible solution would be to add a layer of indirection. Don't hard-code the return type as is, but make it *depend* indirectly on the template parameter, say from a traits class.

Something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct ClassMethodReturn { typedef T type; };

template<>
struct ClassMethodReturn<int> { typedef double type; };

template<typename Type>
class Class {
    typedef typename ClassMethodReturn<Type>::type ret_type;
    ret_type Method(Type Argument) { return ret_type(); }
};

template <>
double Class<int>::Method(int Argument) { return 0.0; }
```

Thus you control the return type for each specialization rather easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another workaround using `std::enable_if`.

```
template<typename Type>
class Class {
    public: 
    template <typename TypeDat=Type> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<TypeDat,int>::value,double> Method(Type Argument) {
        std::cout<<"case 1"<<std::endl;    
    }
    template <typename TypeDat=Type> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<TypeDat,int>::value,Type> Method(Type Argument) {
        std::cout<<"case 2"<<std::endl;
    }

};
int main() {
    Class<int> a;
    a.Method(5);   //print case 1
    Class<char> b;
    b.Method('c'); //print case 2
}
```

### [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6161df87127a97a)

Personally, I love StoryTeller's solution.